# Yahoo OAuth2 private profile - read only permission for private profile

Tags: permissions, yahoo-api, python-social-auth

I'm setting up social auth using Python Social Auth and Yahoo OAuth2. The only purpose if this is to easily register and authenticate. I'm not going to use any Yahoo API at this moment. I want to associate user account in my website with yahoo e-mail address. That's all.

I created an app on https://developer.yahoo.com/ and I puzzled by their permissions model.

1. Read public
2. Read/Write public
3. Read/Write Public and Private

To obtain e-mail address I must access private profile, but I do not understand why on earth I need to get write permission to do that? Is there a more granular permissions model for yahoo apps, hidden somewhere in app configuration?